# b-table and row elements functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm new to Vue and bootstrap-vue and I have the following table in which I pass the functions below to execute when the rows are clicked:

```
<b-table
  striped
  :items="currentCareerReactive.assessmentApplicationsInfo"
  :fields="tableFields"
  @row-clicked="clickTableRow"
>
</b-table>

...

clickTableRow( item, index ) {
  console.log('[dashboard.vue] clickTableRow()');
  this.goToDetailsPage( 
    this.currentCareerReactive.lastAssessmentApplicationResult.assessmentApplicationPublicId );
},

goToDetailsPage( dId ) {
  this.$router.push( { name: 'details', params: { dId, id: this.$route.params.id } } );
},
```

But after I click on the row, [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD48P.png) appear.

The next page loads without any flaws but this error bugs me. It happens after the destroy() of the old page and before the beforeCreate() of the new page.

If I call this function through a button, the page loads normally without any errors so my guess is something on the b-table is causing this.

Does anybody have an idea of what it could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using BootstrapVue 2.1.0, which has a bug in the row-hovered event handler in `<b-table>` and `<b-table-lite>`.  Upgrade to the latest BootstrapVue v2.2.0+ which has a fix for this issue.

See the changelog at https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/misc/changelog#bug-fixes-v220

Comment: Welp, such a simple solution.
Thanks Troy!